# How to send mail from business accout in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail from outlook corporate mail account using Java.
I found few solutions in StackOverflow but that didn't really help.

Here is my java code

```
String host = "smtp.office365.com"; 
final String user = "my_corporate_username"; 
final String  pass = "my_corporate_password"; 
props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
    }
};

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setText("Hey, this is the testing email.");
msg.setSubject("Testing");
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from_mail_id));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to_mail_id));

Transport.send(msg);
```

The output is

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BM1PR01CA0077.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:914)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:825)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:730)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Main.sendMail(Main.java:109)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

The above code worked when I used my personal outlook account. The error probably has occurred because of some authentication factors.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked with your admin that you are allowed to access the corporate mail account? Maybe the access is restricted.

Comment: Of course, i am using my corporate email in corporate network! It should be accessible right?

Comment: Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and see if the protocol trace provides any more details about why the authentication is failing.  You might also have to set the `mail.debug.auth` property to true to get the details of the authentication failure.  But most likely it's something in the configuration of your corporate account that's preventing it from working.  Can you configure Thunderbird to work with your corporate account?